# List data in a table that is not in a view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

`Table1` has columns

`Id int, Date smalldatetime.`

`View1` has, among many other columns, column `Id int`.

`View1` has a maximum of `2000 rows`, but there are some rather complex computation to determine the values of all the columns.

What is the most efficient way to return all `Table1.Id` that are not in `View1.Id` for `Table1.Date` between `'2012-05-30'` and `'2012-05-31'` ?

The filtered selection from `Table1` typically returns about `200 unique` `Table1.Id.`

When I do a SELECT * FROM View1, the total data is returned always in under one second.  When I do a SELECT Id from Table1 WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-05-30' AND '2012-05-31', the result is always instanteous.

The moment I tried SELECT Table1.Id from Table1 T1 WHERE Date BETWEEN .. AND .. AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id from View1 WHERE ViewId=T1.Id), it takes ages (almost 20s).

I tried using a CTE also, WITH V1 as (SELECT Id from View1) SELECT T1.Id FROM Table1 T1 WHERE Date BETWEEN ... and ... AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id from V1 WHERE V1.Id=T1.Id), and it also took ages.

Thanks.

Comment: I understand that the view has calculations to determine the values of the columns, but what determines which *rows* are in the view? Can you show the view, or at least the WHERE clause? Depending on several factors, materializing the view at runtime (and thus performing all of those calculations for nothing) can be more expensive than using other means to determine presence/absence. Also, can you be less ambiguous about the date range? Between is a terrible way to describe this. Do you want all the data from May 30 only, May 30th and May 31st, or something else? Does [Date] include time?

Comment: @leppie: I did a left outer join on View1 and looking for null.  It took too long, ie the time wasn't proportional to one query to View1.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: sorry the date filter has become a distraction.  What I wanted to say was that the filtered list from Table1 returns around 200 rows always, so can this information be used to optimize the overall query.

Comment: My original question arises because the query is taking too long.  It seems like View1 is computed once for every value of Table1.Id.

Comment: Impossible to tell unless you can provide the execution plan and/or more information about the view - definition, how it relates to Table1, how rows are included/excluded, etc. I'm not asking for more information just to be a pain, it really is valuable information that without would just yield wild guesses and conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.[Date]
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
LEFT HASH JOIN dbo.View1 AS v ON v.Id = t.Id
WHERE t.[Date] >= '20120530' AND t.[Date] < '20120531'
AND v.Id IS NULL
```

The HASH hint forces the SQL Server query optimizer to evaluate the view only once.

Another way would be to use a table variable to store the result of the view:

```
DECLARE @ViewResult TABLE (Id int PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @ViewResult 
SELECT Id FROM dbo.View1

SELECT Id, [Date]
FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE [Date] >= '20120530' AND [Date] < '20120531'
AND Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @ViewResult)
```

Razvan

Comment: Thanks!  LEFT HAS JOIN is just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

With little else to go on, I would say that if the view must be referenced then:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.[Date]
  FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
  WHERE t.[Date] >= '20120530'
  AND t.[Date] < '20120531'
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.View1 AS v
    WHERE v.Id = t.Id
  );
```

But I suspect you can do something more efficient here if you can bypass the view.

Comment: I did this, but it took too long, ie not proportional to one computation of getting the view.

Comment: @OldGeezer Then please provide the definition of the view. Also it would be useful if you could share the actual execution plan for this query that takes too long. Might not be the query that needs fixing, but indexes...

Comment: before I discuss the details of View1, which are complex, may I know in your proposed solution whether View1 is computed just once or once for each value of Table1.Id that is returned?

Comment: It shouldn't be, but I honestly have no idea. Not because I'm dumb, but because you haven't shared enough information about YOUR VIEW. You came here for help, right? I'm not going to pull teeth. Going to bed. Good luck.

Comment: I SELECT Id FROM View1 and put the results in a temp table and then use your query.  It is now near instantaneous.